# How to display a div based on loggedin or not in react?

Tags: reactjs

I want to display a div if a user is not LoggedIn. 
I am creating login and logout from Header Component but want to display a div in Child component.

I am creating login and logout from Header Component but want to display a div in Child component. Login code is written in Header Component.

Code for a child component -

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './ReferCandidate.css'
import Header from '../Partials/Header';
import topimage from '../../Resources/Images/slide1.jpg';
import Footer from '../Partials/Footer';

export default class ReferSpecialization extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            hidden: true,
            password: ""
        };

        this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
        this.toggleShow = this.toggleShow.bind(this);
    }

    handlePasswordChange(e) {
        this.setState({ password: e.target.value });
    }

    toggleShow() {
        this.setState({ hidden: !this.state.hidden });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);

        // get homepage category
        var requestedId = this.props.match.params.id;
        var apiUrl = `thisthisthis.com/getJobDetails/${requestedId}`;
        fetch(apiUrl)
            .then(getresponse => {
                return getresponse.json();

            }).then(data => {


                this.setState(
                    {
                        jobid: data.Detail._id,
                        jobtitle: data.Detail.jobTitle,
                        jobdecsription: data.Detail.description,
                        companyNane: data.Detail.companyNane,
                        category: data.Detail.category && data.Detail.category.name,
                        loading: false
                    }
                );

            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container-fluid">
                <Header />
                <div className="inner-slide">
                    <img src={topimage} className="img-fluid homepage-top-image" />
                    <div class="refer-centered">
                        <h2 className="render-image-text">Refer a <br /><span className="job-color">CANDIDATE</span></h2>
                        <p className="render-image-para">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row software">
                        <h1>{this.state.jobtitle}</h1>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div className="container candidate-form">
                    <form>
                        <div className="padded">
                            <div class="form-group row referral">
                                <h1 className="heading">Remember you can refer only two candidates</h1>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col col-form-label">Name of Referral</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                                    <input class="form-control input" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col col-form-label">Linkedin URL</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                                    <input class="form-control input" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                                    <label for="inputEmail3" class="col col-form-label">Upload Resume</label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                                    <span class="btn btn-file">
                                        Browse <input type="file" />
                                    </span>
                                    <span style={{ fontSize: "18px" }}> OR </span>
                                    <span class="btn btn-file">
                                        ITReferral.com <input type="file" />
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {localStorage.usertoken && localStorage.usertoken != 'undefined' ?
                                "" :
                                (
                                    <div>
                                        <div class="form-group row referral">
                                            <h1 className="heading-profile">Create a Profile</h1>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                                                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col col-form-label">Username</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control input" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                                                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col col-form-label">Email</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                                                <input type="email" class="form-control input" id="inputEmail3" />
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-8">
                                                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col col-form-label">Password</label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                                                <input
                                                    type={this.state.hidden ? "password" : "text"}
                                                    value={this.state.password}
                                                    onChange={this.handlePasswordChange}
                                                    class="form-control input"
                                                /><i class="fa fa-eye" onClick={this.toggleShow} aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>)

                            }
                            <div class="form-group row">
                                <div class="col submit">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg submit-button">SUBMIT</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <Footer />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

and code for a header component is -

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Link, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Header.css'
import logo from '../../Resources/Images/logo.png';
import LoadingSpinner from '../loadingspinner.component';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal';
import { login } from "../UserFunctions";
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';

const emailRegex = RegExp(/^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+@([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$/)

const formValid = formErrors => {
    let valid = true;
    Object.values(formErrors).forEach(val => {
        val.length > 0 && (valid = false)
    });
    return valid;
}

class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            show: false,
            email: "",
            name: "",
            password: "",
            loading: false,
            message: '',
            formErrors: {
                email: "",
                password: ""
            }
        };

        this.handleShow = () => {
            this.setState({ show: true });
        };

        this.handleHide = () => {
            this.setState({ show: false });
        };

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (localStorage.usertoken && localStorage.usertoken != 'undefined') {
            const token = localStorage.usertoken;

            const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
            console.log(decoded);
            this.setState({
                name: decoded.name
            })
        }
    }

    onChange(e) {
        const { name, value } = e.target;
        // console.log("name :", name);
        // console.log("value :", value);
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
        let formErrors = this.state.formErrors;

        switch (name) {
            case 'email':
                formErrors.email = emailRegex.test(value) ? '' : "Invalid Email Address";
                break;
            case 'password':
                formErrors.password = value.length < 6 ? 'Minimum 6 character required' : "";
                break;
            default: break;
        }
        this.setState({ formErrors, [name]: value }, () => console.log(this.state));
    }

    logOut(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        localStorage.removeItem("usertoken");
        this.props.history.push("/");
    }

    onSubmit(e) {

        if (formValid(this.state.formErrors)) {
            this.setState({
                loading: true,
            })
            e.preventDefault();
            const user = {
                email: this.state.email,
                password: this.state.password
            };

            login(user).then((res, err) => {

                if (res.Success == '0') {
                    this.setState({
                        loading: false,
                        message: res.Message
                    })
                }
                else {
                    if (localStorage.usertoken && localStorage.usertoken != 'undefined') {
                        const token = localStorage.usertoken;

                        const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
                        console.log(decoded);
                        this.setState({
                            name: decoded.name
                        })
                    }
                    this.handleHide();
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.error('FORM ERROR - DISPLAY ERROR MESSAGE');
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { loading, message } = this.state;
        const { formErrors } = this.state;

        const loginRegLink = (
            <div className="" style={{ display: 'inline-flex' }}>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a onClick={this.handleShow} class="nav-link" style={{ cursor: 'pointer' }} >Login&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/">SignUp&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                </li>
            </div>
        );

        const userLink = (
            <div className="" style={{ display: 'inline-flex' }}>
                <li class="nav-item">

                    <Link className="nav-link" to="/">{this.state.name}</Link>

                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="" onClick={this.logOut.bind(this)} className="nav-link">
                        Logout
          </a>
                </li></div>

        );

        return (
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-basic" >
                <Link to="/">
                    <img src={logo} />
                </Link>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse w-100 flex-md-column" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto small mb-2 mb-md-0">
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                <img className="country-image" src="https://www.countryflags.io/be/shiny/64.png" />&nbsp;English
                        </a>
                            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        {localStorage.usertoken && localStorage.usertoken != 'undefined' ? userLink : loginRegLink}
                    </ul>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto small mb-2 mb-md-0">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/">Join S.i. <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/">AboutUs</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="/">ContactUs</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>


                {/* model popup */}
                <Modal
                    show={this.state.show}
                    onHide={this.handleHide}
                    dialogClassName="modal-90w"
                    aria-labelledby="example-custom-modal-styling-title"
                    centered
                    size="md"
                >
                    <Modal.Header closeButton>
                        <Modal.Title id="example-custom-modal-styling-title text-center">
                            IT Referrals Login
            </Modal.Title>
                    </Modal.Header>
                    <Modal.Body>
                        <div class="form-group" id="sampleTableForEmployee">
                            {message !== '' &&
                                <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
                                    {message}
                                </div>
                            }
                            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                                <div className="row">

                                    <div className="col-md-12">
                                        <div className="input-class-field">
                                            <div className="form-group">
                                                <label htmlFor="email"><b>Email</b></label>
                                                <div className="input-group">
                                                    <span className="input-group-addon">
                                                        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" />
                                                    </span>
                                                    <input
                                                        type="email"
                                                        className='form-control'
                                                        id="email"
                                                        name="email"
                                                        style={{ width: '100%' }}
                                                        placeholder="anyone@example.com"
                                                        required="required"
                                                        value={this.state.email}
                                                        onChange={this.onChange}
                                                    />
                                                    {formErrors.email && (
                                                        <span className="errorMessage" style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: '14px' }}>{formErrors.email}</span>
                                                    )}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="form-group">
                                                <label htmlFor="password"><b>Password</b></label>
                                                <div className="input-group">
                                                    <span className="input-group-addon">
                                                        <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" />
                                                    </span>
                                                    <input
                                                        type="password"
                                                        className={formErrors.password.length > 0 ? 'error form-control' : 'form-control'}
                                                        style={{ width: '100%' }}
                                                        id="password"
                                                        name="password"
                                                        placeholder="********"
                                                        required="required"
                                                        value={this.state.password}
                                                        onChange={this.onChange}
                                                    />
                                                    {formErrors.password.length > 0 && (
                                                        <span className="errorMessage" style={{ color: 'red', fontSize: '14px' }}>{formErrors.password}</span>
                                                    )}
                                                </div>
                                            </div>

                                            <div className="form-group">
                                                <button
                                                    type="submit"
                                                    className="btn btn-primary btn-block pull-right"
                                                    id="btnContactUs"
                                                >
                                                    {loading ? <LoadingSpinner /> : "Login"}
                                                </button><br /><br />
                                                {/* <p className="forgetpassword"><a href="">Forget my password ?</a></p> */}
                                                {/* <p className="signup">Don't have an account? <Link to="/register"> Create Now</Link> </p> */}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>


                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <hr />

                    </Modal.Body>
                </Modal>
                {/* end modal popup */}
            </nav >
        )
    }
}

export default withRouter(Header);
```

So how Can I display the div using localstorage usertoken ?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `getItem` method from `localStorage`  its return the  value or null if key not exists.

Then, in the secondary component, you can verify if the user has logged in or not in this way

The state:

```
state = { isAuth: false };
```

In `componentDidMount`

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ isAuth: localStorage.getItem("auth-token") || false });
  }
```

And in the `render` method

```
 render() {
    let { isAuth } = this.state;
    return isAuth ? (
      <div>
        <h3>Hello user</h3>
        <button onClick={this.logOut}>Logout</button>
      </div>
    ) : (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.login}>Login</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

But this is a very basic example, i think the best way is using a hoc, so if you want to see more details see [this](https://riptutorial.com/reactjs/example/30238/higher-order-component-that-checks-for-authentication) post